# Check for Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a website I am building with asp.net. I am trying to incorporate a username check based off their username of their pc. I get this

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When a new user that is not in my SQL Server database tries to access the site. I would like to add an "if" statement that would redirect them to my error page.

What do I put in my if statement to catch that error instead of getting the error page.

Here is part of my code so you can know what names I am using

```vb
Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("randomserverstuff")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim returnValue As Object

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT RESTRICTED FROM USERS WHERE Username='" & Replace(Page.User.Identity.Name, "domain\", "") & "'"

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

sqlConnection1.Open()

returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

sqlConnection1.Close()

If Session(returnValue)!= Null) Or returnValue.ToString = "Y" Then
```

that last line, the first part of the is statement is what I'm trying to build and cant seem to catch that error in it. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you debug this code?  Chances are `returnValue` is equal to `Nothing` and then you try to convert Nothing ToString which causes your Object Reference error.  Check if returnValue is Nothing and that should solve your problem.  You should also read about Try/Catch blocks, parameterized queries and/or stored procedures.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: yes i tried if return value is nothing and get the same, when i debug i get An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_g3atinjy.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: about SQL injection - how would they use sql injection to bypass their pc username with my sql statement?

Comment: Thats is not how you check for null/Nothing in VB...maybe it is an ASP thing?

Comment: returnvalue is coming back as "Nothing" but it still happens when i try isNothing(returnValue) , returnValue.ToString = "Nothing"

Comment: Surely there is a way to say if returnvalue or  the return data from sql(result)  is null then do this

Comment: Parameterization: `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT RESTRICTED FROM USERS WHERE Username=@1"`. And create parameter and add it to `command` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after no luck I decided to check for row count before running my statement and if rows = 0 to return y and if rows is greater to run a seperate sql statement to determine the result of the restricted column.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
If Session(returnValue)!= Null)
```

Really, is this vb or c#  - neither one!!
Considering that `returnValue` can be `Nothing` the right way would be:

```
If returnValue IsNot Nothing AndAlso Session(returnValue) IsNot Nothing Then
```

Declare `returnValue` as `String`, VB will convert it for you implicitly.